# OpenGL Move object to follow rotating object

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, rotation, glew

I'm working on a construction project in OpenGL and I have one object (object A) which is a digger arm that has another object (object B) which is the scoop/bucket connected to it. Object A is rotated around the Y axis which performs the intended functionality to raise the arm, and I need Object B to always be located on the end of Object A.

Any help on how to do this?

I've created and rotated the object by:

rcontext.PushModelMatrix();

rcontext.Translate(Arms->GetTranslation()[0], Arms->GetTranslation()[1], Arms->GetTranslation()[2]);

rcontext.RotateX(-arms * 100);

Arms->Draw(rcontext);

rcontext.PopModelMatrix();

And now I need to get the bucket to follow the movement of this arm. The object itself has a vertexdata float* that might be useful, but I don't believe each object has its own matrix, rather I have the model view projection matrices for the world. I find it odd that I've struggled to find resources on this as it must be a fairly common usage.

Comment: It's hard to give any code advice without seeing yours. You'll want to get the forward vector of `A` (if you can't get that from the object itself then it should just be the third row of object A's matrix), normalise it and multiply out by however far you want B to be from A.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/).

Comment: Added some more info to the question, I hope it helps!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16510129/3871028

Answer (score 0):

Express the bucket's transform M_bucket as a transform from the boom's transform M_boom. Then, to get the world-position of the bucket, you must multiply the matricies:

M_bucket,world = M_bucket,boom * M_boom,world

Comment: Read your own answer. Do you think it's enough for some one (like the OP) who don't understand composed transformation, likely because doesn't understand what a transformation is?